# search suggestion in sharepoint 2016 should come with its belonging icon

Tags: search, 2016, document, search-box

In SharePoint 2016 search box webpart, I need search suggestion with its icon
like if its a `.doc` then document icon with text or if its an pdf or xlsx then icon of pdf or xlsx along with search suggestion.

And same should happen with some site content along with site icon.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if I search with word 'commissions' and if it exists in 3 documents and 2 PDF and one home page of site then in search suggestion it should come thrice with document icon, twice with PDF icon and once with site icon.

Comment: You are saying "Search Suggestion" do you mean a Promoted Result or a Result Block?